# table-valued parameter without type definition

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to create a table-valued parameter which has not a pre-defined type definition?

I want to create a stored procedure which can take ANY table as an argument, and then within the procedure, the table is analyzed and the data is processed with dynamic sql.
Is that possible?

Comment: No, a table type parameter must be defined. The fact that you want an SP that doesn't have a definition infers a design flaw or an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to create a generic stored procedure which can insert some given data into ANY table. The procedure should therefore create dynamic sql (insert operations)

Comment: *"I want to create a generic stored procedure which can insert some given data into ANY table"* Don't. SQL isn't a programming language. Create objects specific to objects. Creating objects that are "common" between many is a great idea in programming, yes, but you aren't programming. Such generic things are normally only detrimental to the system.

Comment: So you would suggest to better create a function in C#, which is creating dynamic sql and passing it to the server?

Comment: No, I suggest *"Create objects specific to objects"*

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with @Larnu, that's impossible to create a table-valued parameter which has not a pre-defined type definition.

No matter which ways you use, even with csv file, the data all have the default type definition: "String".